# Navigation property is always null

Tags: entity-framework-core

Navigation property is always null by default  ef core (v3.1.0)

But when I load the navigation property with early loading it works.

```
            var companies = context.Companies.Include(e=>e.Employees); // this works
            var e1 = companies.First().Employees;

            var companies = context.Companies; // this does n't work
            var e1 = companies.First().Employees; // error
```

Am I missing something? The following is the sample code to reproduce the issue.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=75UdrcwNs7

Thanks,
Holy

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Add the nuget package  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

On DataContext class enable the following (**UseLazyLoadingProxies**)

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Orders")
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not missing anything. Related properties should be loaded manually like in your first code snippet. This is to keep database operations simple and efficient, the idea is to load only what you really need in that operation.
More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

For sure, you can use lazy loading as in answer above but often it is not recommended to do that.